# The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm very new to tensorflow and trying to make a simple binary classifier for my own image set. They are all grayscale 226x226 PNG images. I keep getting the error "ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`". I have been stuck on this for days and can't seem to shape my model/dataset in a way that works. Can someone help a newb out? Any possibly relevant code should be below. Thanks in advance.

```
##img parser
def _parse_function(filename, label):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_string)
  image_decoded = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded,[226,226])
  return image_decoded, label

#img processor function
#input: dir
#output: dataset
def imgPrcs(dir):
    labelArr = [];
    filenames = [];
    src = dir;

    for fname in os.listdir(src):
        png = os.path.join(src, fname);
        filenames.append(png);
        if os.path.isfile(png):
            #extract label
            with open(png, 'rb') as fobj:
                data = fobj.read()
            data_arr = [];
            for chunk_type, chunk_data in chunk_iter(data):
                if   chunk_type == b'iTXt':
                    data_arr.append(chunk_data.decode());
            label = int(data_arr[1][-1:]);

            #add label
            labelArr.append(label);

    labels = tf.constant(labelArr)
    filename_q = tf.constant(filenames)

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filename_q, labels))
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)

    #return variables
    return dataset;

#create labels and datasets
print('Compiling images and labels...\n');
trainData = imgPrcs('./train/');
testData = imgPrcs('./test/');
valData = imgPrcs('./validate/');


#Create Model
print('Creating Model...\n');
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(226, 226, None)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal', activation='sigmoid')
])

print('compile...\n')
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy']);


print('train..\n')
#Train Model
model.fit(trainData.make_one_shot_iterator(), epochs=5, steps_per_epoch=385)

print('test')
#Test Model
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(testData.make_one_shot_iterator());

print('Test accuracy:', test_acc);
```

Comment: Why did you set the input shape to (226,226,None)?

Comment: I got a different error from yours: `ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined (got (226, 226, None). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.`

Comment: That was a misunderstanding on my part having (226,226,None). However changing it to (226,226) gives "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()". Why would it return an empty array?

Comment: `None` in `.flatten` layer does not make sense, here. Flatten layer is used to convert the tensor into 1D array. From Tensorflow documentation, `Flattens an input tensor while preserving the batch axis (axis 0)`. Since you have `226x226` grayscale images, you input shape is `226 X 226 X 1` for one single data example. If you use batches, then it will be `[batch_size, image_height, image_width, number_of_channels]`. In your case, if you flatten it, you should have a layer with shape `[batch_size, 51076]` where 226 * 226 = 51076